# How can I make elements of varying length not overlap with other elements?

Tags: css

I make fixed bar on page's top by apache tiles.

but the bar is overlapped with sidebar and contents layer.

I tried to setting padding top.

But fixed top bar's height is variable.

Setting padding top at Fixed top bar is Inappropriate.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVYUl.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMHJK.png)

Header part

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>


<header>
<nav
    class="navbar navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark flex-md-nowrap p-0 shadow w-100">
    <a class="navbar-brand col-sm-3 col-md-2 mr-0"
        href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/">Hae Cheol's Web</a> <input
        class="form-control form-control-dark col-md-8 w-100" type="text"
        placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">



    <c:if test="${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name ==null }">
        <div class="navbar-nav px-3 col-md-2">
            <a class="nav-link btn" style="text-align: left;"
                href="<c:url value="/login"/> ">Login </a>
        </div>
    </c:if>

    <c:if test="${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name != null}">
        <div class="navbar-nav px-3 col-md-2">
            <c:if test="${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name == 'admin'}">

                <a class="nav-link btn button-1" href="<c:url value="/admin"/>">AdminPage</a>

            </c:if>

            <a class="nav-link btn button-1"
                href="javascript:document.getElementById('logout').submit()">Logout</a>

            <form id="logout" action="<c:url value="/logout"/>" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
                    value="${_csrf.token}" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </c:if>

</nav>

</header>
```

Body part

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>


        <main role="main" style="margin-top:30px;" class="col-md-9 ml-sm-auto col-lg-10 px-4">
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap align-items-center pt-3 pb-2 mb-3 border-bottom">
            <h1 class="h2">Dashboard</h1>
            <div class="btn-toolbar mb-2 mb-md-0">
              <div class="btn-group mr-2">
                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Share</button>
                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Export</button>
              </div>
              <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle">
                <span data-feather="calendar"></span>
                This week
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>

<canvas class="my-4" id="myChart" width="900" height="380"></canvas>

<h2>Section title</h2>
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-sm">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Header</th>
                <th>Header</th>
                <th>Header</th>
                <th>Header</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1,001</td>
                <td>Lorem</td>
                <td>ipsum</td>
                <td>dolor</td>
                <td>sit</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1,002</td>
                <td>amet</td>
                <td>consectetur</td>
                <td>adipiscing</td>
                <td>elit</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1,003</td>
                <td>Integer</td>
                <td>nec</td>
                <td>odio</td>
                <td>Praesent</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1,003</td>
                <td>libero</td>
                <td>Sed</td>
                <td>cursus</td>
                <td>ante</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1,004</td>
                <td>dapibus</td>
                <td>diam</td>
                <td>Sed</td>
                <td>nisi</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1,005</td>
                <td>Nulla</td>
                <td>quis</td>
                <td>sem</td>
                <td>at</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1,006</td>
                <td>nibh</td>
                <td>elementum</td>
                <td>imperdiet</td>
                <td>Duis</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1,007</td>
                <td>sagittis</td>
                <td>ipsum</td>
                <td>Praesent</td>
                <td>mauris</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1,008</td>
                <td>Fusce</td>
                <td>nec</td>
                <td>tellus</td>
                <td>sed</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1,009</td>
                <td>augue</td>
                <td>semper</td>
                <td>porta</td>
                <td>Mauris</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1,010</td>
                <td>massa</td>
                <td>Vestibulum</td>
                <td>lacinia</td>
                <td>arcu</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1,011</td>
                <td>eget</td>
                <td>nulla</td>
                <td>Class</td>
                <td>aptent</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1,012</td>
                <td>taciti</td>
                <td>sociosqu</td>
                <td>ad</td>
                <td>litora</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1,013</td>
                <td>torquent</td>
                <td>per</td>
                <td>conubia</td>
                <td>nostra</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1,014</td>
                <td>per</td>
                <td>inceptos</td>
                <td>himenaeos</td>
                <td>Curabitur</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1,015</td>
                <td>sodales</td>
                <td>ligula</td>
                <td>in</td>
                <td>libero</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</main>


<!-- Graphs -->
<script
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type : 'line',
        data : {
            labels : [ "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday",
                    "Friday", "Saturday" ],
            datasets : [ {
                data : [ 15339, 21345, 18483, 24003, 23489, 24092, 12034 ],
                lineTension : 0,
                backgroundColor : 'transparent',
                borderColor : '#007bff',
                borderWidth : 4,
                pointBackgroundColor : '#007bff'
            } ]
        },
        options : {
            scales : {
                yAxes : [ {
                    ticks : {
                        beginAtZero : false
                    }
                } ]
            },
            legend : {
                display : false,
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, please include your HTML and CSS in your question, thanks

Comment: Include your html and css. You an have a spacer section between the header and content and set a fixed height to the section to bring down the content..

Comment: I add HTML and CSS code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need Javascript to accomplish what you want. Hope this helps.

```js
document.onscroll = function() {
  /* When scrolled, set the header to position: fixed; */
  const header = document.getElementById("header");
  if (header.style.position !== "fixed") {
    header.style.position = "fixed";
    header.style.top = 0;
    /* Retrieve the height of the header and assign top margin to container */
    const headerHeight = header.clientHeight;
    document.getElementById("container").style.marginTop = headerHeight + "px";
  }
};
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px; /* This can be anything */
  background-color: blue;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

aside {
  background-color: green;
  width: 25%;
}

.content {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 75%;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<header id="header"></header>
<div id="container">
  <aside></aside>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```